# How to say ''I'm going out to buy myself something''

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

I want to say "I'm going out to buy myself a sandwich". I would say it if I'm hungry and want to get out of my house to buy some fast food.
I tried with Google Translate and these are the answers:

1. Ich gehe mir ein Sandwich kaufen.*
2. Ich gehe aus mir ein Sandwich zu kaufen.*

Then, I also tried "I''ll buy myself a sandwich", which seemed right, but I'm not sure (I'm learning German by myself), this was the answer:

1. Ich werde mir ein Sandwich kaufen.
2. Ich kaufe mir ein Sandwich.*

(I edited this question since it wasn't very detailed.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to GermanSE. We do not do translation requests and although you put in the effort and put it into google translate, this question is missing what you think the right answer should be and why. Could you try to be clearer where you are struggling? Since you are already learning German, perhaps you are able to write down an easier version of the sentence.

Comment: Probably this kind of question has now priority and could be exceptionally allowed (bzgl. etwaiger Ausgangssperre), or [edit]ed with some more descriptive title.

Comment: Please consider including why you think there is something wrong. If you learn German by yourself, I assume you found some rules and stuff. So there is a list to check against why you think your results were wrong/ not fully right.

Answer (score 4):

These are two questions.

I answer them in German because it seems your purpose is anyway learning German.

1) *Ausgehen* wird vor allem verwendet für Dinge wie "ins Restaurant gehen", "bummeln gehen", etc., also für Aktivitäten außer Haus, die man als genussvoll empfindet. *Ich gehe aus, mir ein Sandwich zu kaufen* ist darum zwar grammatisch korrekt, klingt aber seltsam. Ein Muttersprachler würde das schlichtweg nicht sagen.

2) *Ich werde mir ein Sandwich kaufen* und *Ich kaufe mir ein Sandwich* sind beide grammatisch korrekt, der erste Satz mit Futur, der andere mit Präsens. In Alltagskommunikation können sie trotzdem als synonym gelten - oder als "synsituativ" (die gleiche Situation betreffend): Der Sprecher teilt mit, welche Aktivität er in unmittelbarer Zukunft zu unternehmen gedenkt. - Im Alltagsdeutsch wird Futur nur sehr selten verwendet. Man sagt auch: *Ich glaube, der Trump gewinnt im November die Wahl*, auch wenn das noch acht Monate hin ist und somit eindeutig in der Zukunft liegt. - In schriftlichen Äußerungen höherer Stilebene wird man jedoch in solchen Fällen tatsächlich das Futur verwenden.

Comment: That might serve OP but not other potential readers. Please consider providing an additional English version.